# Change the path for system command parameters

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a C++ project for which I have generated an .exe.

The program has some code as following:

```
system(TestApplication.exe input.txt output.txt)
system(TestApplication1.exe input1.txt output1.txt)
system(TestApplication2.exe input2.txt output2.txt)
```

I actually tried keeping the .exe's inside another folder in the project directory i.e. (EXEs) and files in another one (Data).

It actually cannot find the files if the path for exe is changed. I think there's a problem in changing the path in system as since it tells that EXEs is not a recognized command:

```
system("EXEs/TestApplication1.exe .... )
```

How is the path changed for the system command in C++?

Comment: Why cant you give the whole path of the exe to the system command? To do this have a variable and do sprintf it the path,exe name and the arguments required.

Comment: Because the project directory path keeps on changing from another project. So, I would prefer the path to be realtive

Comment: Then you should always ensure that the executable is present in same directory relative to the project directory and the project directory should be set in an environment variable so that you can access the executable using the project directory path.

Comment: @Raghuram: Can you give a short example of the path for the relative path in system command here, so I could cross check if I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your Project directory is set as

> ```
> set PROJECT_DIR = "C:\myproject\rundir"
> ```

and your executable is inside the project directory and it is inside the folder

> ```
> C:\myproject\myexdir\
> ```

Then what you can do is always use the PROJECT_DIR to locate your executable like

```
char myexe_dir[256];
sprintf(myexe_dir,"%s\\..\\myexdir\\a.exe arg1 arg2",getenv("PROJECT_DIR"));
system(myexe_dir);
```