# How to set path inside of c++ program using system() function

Tags: c++, path, system

I need to write c++ program which sets path using system() function:

```
system("set PATH=%PATH%;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin\\amd64");
system("nvcc -x cu -o cudapair cudapair.c");
```

But it doesnt work. It throws error, because path wasn't set. What's the problem?

Comment: I guess it only works in your program. When it exists the PATH variable is gone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the path for system command parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389592/change-the-path-for-system-command-parameters)

Comment: Put your path in quotation marks.

Comment: I run the system("set PATH=%PATH%;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin\\amd64"); and then another system() to run the program in that path. And both system() calls inside of one program.

Comment: @user - Each call to `system` starts a new, separate, program.

Comment: @BoPersson could you recommend a way to do it in the same program?

Comment: @BoPersson I tried to run commands in one line using '&' and it didnt work either

Answer (score 5):

> I need to write c++ program which sets path using system() function

I'm assuming what you actually need to do is write a C++ program that
sets the `PATH` for the environment in which it will then execute

```
nvcc -x cu -o cudapair cudapair.c
```

You think you need to make that environment setting with
the `system` function, but in fact you don't.

You should understand that a process cannot change *its own* environment.
A process inherits its environment from its *parent* process, and it
can change the environment that is inherited by its *child* processes.

That's why your posted attempt does not work.

```
system("set PATH=%PATH%;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin\\amd64");
```

executes a child process of your program. That child process gets the same environment settings
as your program, and can't change them. What does that child process do? It invokes the
Windows shell to run the commandline:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin\\amd64");
```

This *would* change the environment settings of any more child processes that were started
by *this commandline*. But there aren't any. The commandline makes an environment setting
that no process uses. Your `system` call returns. That environment setting no longer
exists anywhere. Nothing has changed.

You then call:

```
system("nvcc -x cu -o cudapair cudapair.c");
```

which starts a second child process, again with the same environment settings that your
program started with.

**What you should do**

1. Get the value of `PATH` from the environment that your program inherits.
2. Using that value, create the new value of `PATH` that you want to pass to your child process.
3. Put that new value of `PATH` into the environment your child process will inherit.
4. Run your child process.

You use `system` only to do **4**.

To do **1**, use the Microsoft C library function [`getenv_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb2sfw2z.aspx)
(It is a secure variant of the Standard C++ [`std::getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv))

To do **3**, use the Microsoft C library function [`_putenv_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyw7eyfw.aspx) (Note the leading underscore.)

Here is an illustrative program for Visual C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

const std::size_t ENV_BUF_SIZE = 1024; // Enough for your PATH?

int main()
{
    char buf[ENV_BUF_SIZE];
    std::size_t bufsize = ENV_BUF_SIZE;
    int e = getenv_s(&bufsize,buf,bufsize,"PATH");  
    if (e) {
        std::cerr << "`getenv_s` failed, returned " << e << '\n';
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::string env_path = buf;
    std::cout << "In main process, `PATH`=" << env_path << std::endl;
    env_path += ";C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin\\amd64";
    e = _putenv_s("PATH",env_path.c_str());
    if (e) {
        std::cerr << "`_putenv_s` failed, returned " << e << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    e = std::system("echo \"In child process `PATH`=%PATH%\"");
    if (e) {
        std::cerr << "`std::system` failed, returned " << e << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[See it live](http://rextester.com/XUP36069)